# error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript

I got this error while compiling and running this code with my angular application

error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.

on this line:
const id = this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap?.get('id');

full code:

```js
constructor(private shopService: ShopService, private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  loadProduct(){
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-non-null-assertion
    const id = this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap?.get('id');
    this.shopService.getProduct(id).subscribe(product => {
      this.product = product;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

after adding any component I got the page:  cannot GET /

Comment: I modified it also to: 
const id = +this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

but no use

Comment: My guess is the issue is actually in the service..

Comment: No problem in the service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was close, and found the solution from related.
I changed the line:

```
const id = this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap?.get('id');
```

just to be:

```
const id = +this.activateRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')!;
```

and the error disappeared.
Thanks for all

Comment: What the ! mark at the end will do ? @Waleed

Comment: I think mostly is a handle to the nullable value, if the query string parameter was null